# How to extract text with hyperlinks from docx file with python?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

The docx file that i am working on has a hyperlink with a comment on it.

For eg:
https://www.someurl.com/ddoai9101?%20dsadoi - **File with student address**

https://www.someurl.com/ddoai9101?%2a1231w1 - **File with student scores**

I am trying to extract the hyperlink and comment in the excel sheet. I am using python-docx library to extract hyperlink and text. But, the python-docx library will either give you text or hyperlink.
This is how I got the hyperlinks:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT

document = Document("StudentData.docx")
rels = document.part.rels
for rel in rels:
    if rels[rel].reltype == RT.HYPERLINK:
        url = rels[rel]._target
```

and this is how I got the text

```
texts = document.paragraphs
for t in texts:
    print(t.text)
```

Now the problem is the text does not show hyperlink and I don't know which comment is associated with which hyperlink. Is there a way to get text with hyperlinks from docx file with python?

Answer (score -1):

```
    import docx2txt
    text = docx2txt.process(file_path)
```

Comment: docx2text helps you in place of document to extract the text in your file along with hyperlinks

Comment: FYI, you can click on the **[Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73368497/edit)** button under your post to edit/update it. I'm just saying because I see you have an [explanation in the comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73141681/how-to-extract-text-with-hyperlinks-from-docx-file-with-python/73368497#comment129569091_73368497) and a [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73342156/2745495) with some other explanation. Please put all the explanations/descriptions in the post itself, not in the comments.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. In particular, please make sure your answers actually address the question being asked. Specifically _how_ does `doc2txt` help in this regard?